# How to Stop automated scanners from scanning the website Leaving the robots.txt Any other way Configuration can be made?

Tags: automation, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

Do anyone knows how to stop Automated Scanners from Scanning the Web Application or website ?
 Leaving the robots.txt Any other way Configuration can be made?
Any server side
 modification?

Comment: Add a robots.txt with a Disallow: section

Comment: not everyone respects robots.txt

Comment: Leaving robots.txt any other way?

Comment: You may need to check for web application firewall.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a **/robots.txt** file that can ask scanners nicely not to scan all or parts of your site. Most *legitimate* search engine robots follow the instructions you put in robots.txt

For example:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /api/
```

2. If you want to be more fancy pants, you can add a http get on **/api/** that normal browsers won't access. Your application HTML may access **/api/customers** and **/api/suppliers** but never **/api/** for example.

When an automated scanner reads **/api/**, you can reject any further requests from that IP for 10 minutes. It may help a little.

3. A [Web Application Firewall](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) like [OWASP ModSecurity](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) may also help

Comment: leaving robots.txt any other thing that can be done on server as a part of security ?

Comment: Adding something more fancy like I suggested may help a little.